# BiometricPrompt onAuthenticationSucceeded error when closing parent activity

Tags: android, androidx

On my application i created an activity dedicated to authentication, in case of the biometric prompt, i need to close the activity when the atuhentication is completed succesfully.
I'm using androidx stable tree, with biometrics
implementation "androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.1"

```
public class LockScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 protected void waitForAuthentication() {
   FragmentActivity activity = this;
   cryptoObject = new BiometricPrompt.CryptoObject(cipher);
    // Callback for biometric authentication result
    final BiometricPrompt biometricPrompt = new BiometricPrompt(activity, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this), new BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {

        ....

        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(@NonNull BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult result) {
            super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result);
            finish();
        }

        ....
```

when the parent activity is closed i foun in logcat the error
2020-10-29 10:49:40.666 1186-1186/xxxxxxxx E/FingerprintDialogFrag: Failed to dismiss fingerprint dialog fragment. Fragment manager was null.